# steganography using DWT in python

Tags: python, steganography, haar-wavelet, dwt, lsb

I've been doing research on image steganography using DWT. here's my problem: i'm running a code in python and i already got the subbands coefficients of the cover image. but i don't know how to embed the secret image into the cover. A paper says that i can do it by replacing the LSB of the subband coefficient with MSB of the secret image. but is it possible if i want to embed a secret image whose size is more than or equal to the cover image? how?

oh i'm doing 2 level DWT so if the cover image's size is nxn, the subbands coefficients' size will be n/4 x n/4

Comment: This is not really programming related, sounds more like a question about DWT itself. You might have better luck at [dsp.stackexchange.com](http://dsp.stackexchange.com).

Comment: DSP SE would really not be relevant to this. I think it's relevant here because he's asking how to fit Y information into X storage space. The `lsb` tag does not refer to the least significant bit and `python` seems to be useless as the question doesn't provide python related coded and can be answered in a language-agnostic manner. A more descriptive title would also be nice.

Answer (score 0):

If you have X pixels/coefficients/whatever and Y bits to embed, where Y > X, then something has to give.

- Use a bigger cover medium to increase X, or
- embed more than 1 bit per pixel to increase embedding capacity, or
- compress or downsize the secret image to decrease Y.